# Best pattern for modeling sparse attributes

Tags: database-design

I work on a financial services product that stores lots of information on the end-customer. Our clients continuously want to add new attributes, that often that aren't used to drive any process in our product. They are captured and displayed but nothing else. Due to differences in how our clients operate, they often want to store very different values. We have tried two solutions to accomodate them:

1. Sparsely populated tables with 100s of hundred columns.
2. Entity Attribute Value tables where the customer can define new columns as needed.

We have experienced most of the disadvantages of both solutions. Lots of columns provide comfort for us in that we know what data we are adding to our database, but can make us appear inflexible and expensive when a customer 'just' wants to store a new value, like Favourite Golf Club. EAV has shown all of its usual problems: poorly performing queries, losing control of the data, lack of validation and maintainability problems.

So is there a better pattern out there?

Comment: I can't understand what you meant by `Entity Attribute Value tables`. I am eager to help you out

Comment: Have you thought of trying XML?

Comment: @Tauseef See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Comment: So we are on the same page then. thanks. thinking thinking

Comment: Sounds like a job for NoSQL.

Comment: Don't you have situations -- even if rare -- where a client says they want to select all their end-customers who have a certain attribute?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did a presentation about this subject at [Percona Live MySQL Conference & Expo 2013](http://www.percona.com/live/mysql-conference-2013/). My presentation was called [Extensible Data Modeling](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/extensible-data-modeling).

For your situation, since the user-defined attributes are not used in your SQL queries (only captured and displayed as you say), I would recommend the [Serialized LOB](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serializedLOB.html) pattern.

Here's the abstract of my presentation. The slides are freely available:

> Designing an extensible, flexible schema that supports user
>   customization is a common requirement, but it's easy to paint yourself
>   into a corner.
>
> Examples of extensible database requirements:
>
> - A database that allows users to declare new fields on demand.
> - Or an e-commerce catalog with many products, each with distinct attributes.
> - Or a content management platform that supports extensions for custom data.
>
> The solutions we use to meet these requirements is overly complex and
>   the performance is terrible. How should we find the right balance
>   between schema and schemaless database design?
>
> I'll briefly cover the disadvantages of Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV),
>   a problematic design that's an example of the antipattern called the
>   Inner-Platform Effect, That is, modeling an attribute-management
>   system on top of the RDBMS architecture, which already provides
>   attributes through columns, data types, and constraints.
>
> Then we'll discuss the pros and cons of alternative data modeling
>   patterns, with respect to developer productivity, data integrity,
>   storage efficiency and query performance, and ease of extensibility.
>
> - Class Table Inheritance
> - Serialized BLOB
> - Inverted Indexing
>
> Finally we'll show tools like pt-online-schema-change and new features
>   of MySQL 5.6 that take the pain out of schema modifications.

Comment: +1 for the LOB recommendation. One thing worth nothing is that if you *did* want to query on this data it is rather painful to do in this LOB format. The EAV approach is also painful, but more accessible than the LOB.

Comment: @Matthew, check out the Inverted Index solution in my presentation. It helps the LOB solution be more queriable.

Comment: just read it and it's quite clever. I wonder if dealing with the LOB and the inverted index could cause issues with atomicity and isolation? Even if it does though, the consequences of a failure seem low.

Comment: @Matthew, it shouldn't have any trouble with atomicity and isolation if you update the LOB and the inverted index in a single transaction. But I admit it is a hassle to have to update multiple tables. Such is the cost of storing non-relational data in a relational database.

Comment: Thanks Bill. We use DB2 for i which now has support for the XML data type, which I think would allow us to query the data more easily than with LOBs. I'll give it a whirl.

Comment: Aha, yes, having a native indexable XML data type makes user-defined attributes a lot easier. Oracle has that feature too.

Comment: Very good presentation and summary of the options and pros/cons, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would model this as a separate attributes table, **not** a table with multiple "custom" columns... what happens when you have 100 columns and they want to add attribute # 101? What about clients with very few custom attributes? A hundred `NULL` columns...

In this case, your storage type can simply be `VARCHAR(MAX)` because you perform no logic on these columns except to `SELECT` and display them. The consequence is that you have potentially inefficient storage of `INT` or `DATE` types (or whatever disparate types you may want to store) but that is the nature of allowing the client to store *anything* in these custom fields.

Consider a table having five columns:

- Id
- ParentType
- ParentId
- CustomValueName
- CustomValue

So now you have enough information to:

1. Distinctly tie your custom attribute to any other entity in your DB
2. Name the attribute types for custom aggregations if needed
3. Append any value the user wants

The downside is that it's somewhat painful to query on these custom attributes (though it can be done easily in SQL, the query plan won't be very efficient).

Answer (score 0):

i don't think that i can point you to a specific pattern, but you might have heard of [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/).

it's a database that tends to address a lot of diverse problems that usually arise during development of database heavy applications (ie it's possible to script stuff in CoffeeScript and you can access the data via JSON).

they offer an extension called [HSTORE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/hstore.html) that sounds like it would eliminate all of your problems. HSTORE basically allows you to store an arbitrary hash of data in your table. it's even possible to query it.